# ESXi 4.1 iSCSI won't create partition the full size of the Openfiler Volume

Tags: vmware-esxi, iscsi, openfiler

I created an iSCSI volume in Openfiler.

Volume name     Volume description  Volume size     File system type    File system size    FS used space   FS free space   Delete  Properties  Snapshots
backup  Backup Storage  3717536 MB  iSCSI   Not applicable  Not applicable  Not applicable  In use  Edit    Create

When I create the partition in VMware, it sets the size of the partition to 1.55TB even though it detects that the iSCSI volume is 3.7TB. I get this error message in /var/log/messages. Any idea what's happening here??

Comment: what blocksize are you using?

Answer (score 1):

ESXi 4.1 has a maximum extent size of 2 TB.  Break it into separate volumes in OpenFiler and present separately to ESXi, and if desired, glue the extents back together into one datastore there.

Alternatively, upgrade to ESXi 5, where this limit is increased (I want to say I read 64TB somewhere).

*edit:* [Yup, 64TB](http://www.vmware.com/support/vsphere5/doc/vsphere-esx-vcenter-server-50-new-features.html).

> With VMFS5, you can create a 64TB datastore on a single extent.